# ngmodelchange called twice in angular 6 material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a scenario whenever the user is start searching something which will call the http service and get the response and show it in the dropdown.

I have the below code which is working fine with the above approach. But, after we click any option listed from the dropdown, `ngmodelchange` method again calling which fetch the service again. It should not happen.

Where am I missing?

```
<mat-form-field class="half-width">
            <input matInput aria-label="State" name="state" placeholder="Search by number (1 or 2 or 3)" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="currentState"
              (ngModelChange) = "filterInstrument(currentState)">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="state">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let state of insDetails" [value]="state.id">
                  <span>{{state.id}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.userId}}</span> |
                  <span>{{state.title}}</span>                 
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Also is there any possibility to show the selected value (pipe separated) as like shown in the dropdown? Currently `id` property alone is displayed in the selected value.

Complete Code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzcvyw-zaap11?file=app/select-multiple-example.html)

Any help?

Comment: Any help ..........?

Answer (score 1):

To show the current selected option in input add click to mat-option:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of insDetails" [value]="state.id" (click) ="valueGet(state)">
     <span >{{state.id}}</span> |
     <span>{{state.userId}}</span> |
     <span>{{state.title}}</span>                 
</mat-option>
```

In select-multiple-example.ts:

```
valueGet(state) {
   this.currentState = `${state.id} ${state.title} ${state.userId}`;
}
```

Comment: Yes, any idea on the first approach which is called second time when selected?